# ZSH exits with the return code of the last command instead of 0, breaking `remain-on-exit failed` in tmux

Tags: zsh, tmux

The `remain-on-exit failed` option in tmux causes the pane to remain open when exit code isn't 0, to allow me to inspect what happened. In interactive mode, I would expect zsh to always return 0 unless it crashes or is killed. However, this is not what happens.

Example: If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel inputting the current line, and subsequently press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, zsh exits with error code 130 instead of 0.

Doing an `echo $?` and experimenting confirms that after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, zsh is simply returning the exit code of the last command executed, fooling tmux into thinking that it crashed, which is not the case.

How can I change this behavior, and- should I? Would doing so break anything?

Comment: `Ctrl-C` (typically) sends the interrupt signal to the current process (zsh). This is telling it that there's a problem. Hence your results.

You should 'cancel inputting' by clearing the input buffer, not sending a signal. Try `Ctrl-U`.

Comment: @Gedge This is valuable information, thanks- However, it doesn't address the fact that doing e.g. `test() { return 5; }; test;`, followed by `Ctrl+D` will also cause zsh to exit with a non-zero status code, which is also undesirable behavior for me.

Comment: that makes sense to me - your last command returns non-zero, and then you stopped sending commands (EOF), so that non-zero is returned

if you wish to ignore the last command, then you need to not use `Ctrl-D` but use `exit` instead?

Comment: Ah, so a situation analogous to a non-interactive script returning the status of last command executed within it? I wonder if I could rebind `Ctrl+D` to `exit` but only inside zsh... or maybe I should just create a `Ctrl+W` keybind and get used to that instead?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to set the final shell return code to `0` when added to `~/.zshrc`:

```
exitzero() {
  print "in exitzero for process $$"
  exit 0
}
add-zsh-hook zshexit exitzero
```

The print statement is optional; it's just an indicator and has no effect on the return code.

With the call to add the hook in `.zshrc`, it should only be set for interactive shells, so that should limit its effects.  The documentation in the `zshmisc` man page indicates that the `zshexit` hook is only invoked in a limited set of scenarios:

> Executed at the point where the main shell is about to exit normally.
> This is not called by exiting subshells, nor when the exec precommand
> modifier is used before an external command. Also, unlike TRAPEXIT,
> it is not called when functions exit.

I have no idea what other impacts this code might have.  It seems to be a relatively low-risk change - if you try it, please let us know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

When **any** process terminates because it had been killed by a signal, Linux ensures that there a non-zero exit code (larger than 127) is set. The exit code is 128+SIGNALNUMBER; in your case, the signal is 2 (SIGINT), which results in exitcode 130.

However, some signals can be caught. You could catch the catchable signals (using the `trap` command) and do a graceful exit. For instance to catch SIGINT in this way, you would do it by

```
trap 'exit 0' INT
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue - I don't want the shell to exit when I press `Ctrl+C`, I just want it to exit with code 0 after subsequent `Ctrl+D`.

Comment: After the trap, you can put an arbitrary command. For instance, you can put a command which just sets a flag meaning "control-c has been pressed", and then return to your script. You can then evaluate the flag and depending on your logic, either exit, or reset the flag and continue processing.